# "As flores têm sua beleza" ou "suas belezas"?

Tags: número-gramatical, substantivos

Supondo, por exemplo, que cada homem tenha um carro. Então eu poderia dizer:

> Os homens têm seus carros.

Porém, para dizer que cada flor tem beleza, eu diria:

> As flores têm sua beleza.

Isso está certo, ou deveria ser "suas belezas"?
Se sim, que propriedade a palavra "beleza" tem nessa frase que ela pode se comportar diferente da palavra "carro"?

Outros exemplos:

> Os bancários têm seus interesses.
>   Os macacos têm suas caudas.

Comment: beleza é um adjetivo e carro é um substantivo. Só por ai, já é diferente. É um inicio para pesquisa...Mas acho q no caso, suas belezas, a palavra beleza passa a ser um substantivo e assim, concordar com o sujeito.

Comment: Beleza é um substantivo abstrato. Adjetivo seria "as flores são belas" ou "as flores são bonitas".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As flores têm a sua beleza*, é como toda a gente diz.
A grande diferença é que *carro, interesse* e *cauda* dos teu exemplos são concebidos como entidades **contáveis**, enquanto *beleza* é concebida como uma entidade **não contável**. Encontrei [este artigo genérico no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-plural-de-nomes-nao-contaveis/28624)  e há também [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/mass-nouns-in-portuguese) sobre o assunto.

**Entidades contáveis** são concebidas como exemplares individuais, que por isso podem ser contados: um carro, dois carros, três carros; um macaco anormal que nasceu com duas caudas; os bancários têm vários interesses—aumento dos salários, condições de trabalho; redução da idade de aposentação, etc; ou então poderíamos pensar em interesses extraprofissionais, como futebol, canto gregoriano e outras coisas pelas quais os bancários se poderão interessar.

**Entidades não contáveis** poderão sê-lo por várias razões. No teu exemplo, *beleza* é ‘qualidade daquilo que é belo’, que nós concebemos com se fosse uma entidade única que se manifesta em várias coisas, como flores, paisagens, mulheres, etc. Por isso não vamos dizer, neste sentido de *beleza*, “duas beleza, várias belezas”, etc. Mas podemos estabelecer graus: *alguma beleza, grande beleza, extraordinária beleza*,etc. Isto é geralmente válido para outras qualidades:

> Os alunos têm **imensa paciência** para aquele professor (compara com *têm perguntas para o professor*)
>
> Os árabes são conhecidos pela **sua hospitalidade**

Outro tipo de entidades não contáveis são as substâncias, como água, ferro, areia; e ainda outras coisas como poesia, música, dinheiro, etc.:

> Os trabalhadores dizem que a água da empresa sabe mal e trazem **a água deles**
>
> Os bancários ganham **muito dinheiro**

Aqui o que se passa é que, enquanto o meu carro mais o teu carro são dois carros, o meu dinheiro mais o teu dinheiro continua a ser simplesmente dinheiro, não “dois dinheiros”. Do mesmo modo, cada trabalhador traz a sua porção de água, mas várias porções de água continuam a ser simplesmente água.

Frequentemente um substantivo pode referir uma entidade contável num sentido e uma não contável noutro sentido. Compara:

> Os bancários têm **os seus interesses**
>
> Estas casas velhas têm **o seu interesse**

No segundo exemplo, *interesse* é ‘qualidade do que é interessante’, e é não contável.

O mesmo se passa com *beleza*: pode referir não a ‘qualidade do que é belo’ mas ‘algo que é belo’, e esse algo já é contável:

> Venho maravilhado com as belezas (coisas belas) do Rio: o Corcovado, Pão de Açúcar, etc., etc.

Nomes não contáveis, como água, vinho, etc., podem também passar a contáveis se referirem variedades. Compara

> *Temos imenso vinho* versus *temos três vinhos diferentes: um alentejano, um do Douro, e outro chileno*

Isto também funciona com *beleza* enquanto ‘qualidade’:

> Olha a criança e o bisavô: ambos têm beleza, mas são belezas (tipos de beleza) muito diferentes

Portanto não seria disparatado dizer neste sentido “as flores têm as suas belezas”, mas a mim soa-me melhor “cada flor tem a sua beleza” ou “toda a flor tem a sua beleza” (aprendi hoje que no Brasil é “toda flor”…) ou mesmo “todas as flores têm a sua beleza”, em que se subentende que cada uma tem a sua e que são diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

**Ambas as formas estão corretas**.

No entanto o significado é ligeiramente distinto.

*As flores têm sua beleza*: Indica que todas as flores têm uma beleza típica. Vê-se assim que a beleza das flores é uma característica comum a todas as flores (sendo beleza um substantivo abstrato). Não é a mesma coisa que dizer os homens têm seu carro (que significa que todos os homens deste contexto possuem um carro que pertence a um terceiro), mas sim "os homens têm sua masculinidade" ou "os macacos têm sua esperteza".

*As flores têm suas belezas*: É parecido com a primeira forma, porém neste caso as flores têm mais de uma forma de beleza. Outro exemplo que ilustra isso seria "as obras de arte têm suas interpretações".